# How to get detailed information on how "sudo" is failing

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

When I try to `sudo something` I get:
    "    luke is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported."

All sudo users have failure in the same way.

How can I get more detailed information about what exactly is failing here? This used to work fine, but somebody else with sudo access has messed around (?) and now sudo doesn't work (although I can su to root and sudo from there fine.)

I've checked /etc/sudoers (contents and permissions all match my default install, `visudo -c` reports all is OK)

I am definitely still in the sudo group:

```
$ getent group sudo
sudo:x:27:luke,user2,user3
```

When I add

```
 luke    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

to /etc/sudoers it does let me use sudo. but why can't members of the sudo group use it?

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
sudo    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

luke    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

ubuntu 16.04 server edition.

Comment: The default way that Ubuntu gives sudo rights to users is to make them members of the `sudo` group (or, historically, the `admin` group). Perhaps it is the group membership that got messed up, rather than the sudoers configuration? what is the output of `getent group sudo` for example?

Comment: It sounds like you should ask that "somebody with sudo access" what exactly they did while they were messing around...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
sudo    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

The line after the comment *Members of the admin group may gain root privileges* grants sudo access to member of the group `admin`, but the line after *Allow members of group sudo...* has the `%` sign removed from the beginning, and so it only grants sudo access to a **user** named `sudo`, not to a **group** with the same name.

Comment: nailed it. thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is to add user `luke` :

```
visudo
```

then

```
luke   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Comment: this does let me use sudo again, so was definitely a useful shout. I'd really like to work out what the underlying problem is and fix it, but I'll accept in a couple days if I give up and just use this workaround indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

**Causes**
A broken sudo may be caused by any of the following:

1. A user should not have been removed from the `sudo` or `admin group`.
2. The `/etc/sudoers` file was altered to prevent users in `sudo` or `admin group` from elevating their privileges to that of root using `sudo` command.
3. The permission on `/etc/sudoers` file is not set to `0440`.

**Follow the steps below to fix it.**

1. Open a terminal window,
2. Enter `root` using command `su root`
3. Input `root password`
4. Input command `apt-get install sudo -y` to install `sudo`
5. Add user to `sudoers file` by inputting `adduser username` for a new user or `usermod -aG sudo username` for existing user. Put your username in place of username.

   > You can use `usermod -aG sudo,adm username` to add it to both sudoers and admin groupt.
6. Set the correct permissions for `sudoers file` by inputting `chmod  0440  /etc/sudoers`
7. Type `exit` and hit Enter until you close your terminal window.
8. Shutdown your system completely and reboot.
9. Open another terminal window.
10. Try any `sudo` command to check if your username is correctly added to sudoers file. e.g

    `sudo apt-get update`

    If your username has been correctly added to the sudoers list then you will not get the error.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. turned out a small corruption in the "sudo    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" line was the underlying problem